# CSS `background-repeat` property

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am reading HTML and CSS by Jon Duckett and I am learning about the CSS `background-repeat` property.

[image]

Now, I produced the code from `background-repeat` in the code snippet below.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/gE9g95/header.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #665544;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Background Image (Body)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Planting Guide</h1>
  <h2>Magnolia</h2>
  <p><b><i>Magnolia grandiflora</i></b>, commonly known as the <b>Southern magnolia</b> or <b>bull bay</b>, is a tree of the family Magnoliaceae native to the southeastern United States, from coastal Virginia south to central Florida, and west to eastern
    Texas and Oklahoma. Reaching 27.5 m (90 ft) in height, it is a large striking evergreen tree with large dark green leaves and large white fragrant flowers. Widely cultivated around the world, over a hundred cultivars have been bred and marketed commercially.
    The timber is hard and heavy, and has been used commercially to make furniture, pallets, and veneer.</p>
  <h2>Ranunculus</h2>
  <p><b><i>Ranunculus asiaticus (Persian Buttercup)</i></b> is a species of buttercup (Ranunculus) native to the eastern Mediterranean region in southwestern Asia, southeastern Europe (Crete, Karpathos and Rhodes), and northeastern Africa. It is a herbaceous
    perennial plant growing to 45 cm tall, with simple or branched stems. The basal leaves are three-lobed, with leaves higher on the stems more deeply divided; like the stems, they are downy or hairy. The flowers are 3-5 cm diameter, variably red to
    pink, yellow, or white, with one to several flowers on each stem.</p>
  <h2>Tulip</h2>
  <p><b><i>Tulipa gesneriana L. or "Didier's tulip"</i></b> is a plant belonging to the family of Liliaceae. This species has uncertain origins, possibly from Asia, and has become naturalised in south-west Europe. Most of the cultivated species, subspecies
    and cultivars of tulip are derived from Tulipa gesneriana. The flower and bulb can cause dermatitis through the allergen, tuliposide A, even though the bulbs may be consumed with little ill-effect. The sweet-scented bisexual flowers appear during
    April and May. Bulbs are extremely resistant to frost, and can tolerate temperatures well below freezing - a period of low temperature is necessary to induce proper growth and flowering, triggered by an increase in sensitivity to the phytohormone
    auxin. The bulbs may be dried and pulverised and added to cereals or flour.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, my question is this - 
does the `background-image` property, by default, repeat (or "tessellate") the image along the top of the element (in this case, the `body` element)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image is placed according to the background-position property. **If no background-position is specified**, the image is always placed at the element's **Top Left** corner.

By default, a background-image is repeated both vertically and horizontally.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp